# How do you document variables without making the code look so busy?

Tags: typescript, variables, documentation

I was documenting my class variables when I realized it looked very busy. Is there a standard way of documenting variables? Below is my code so far. It looks terrible:

```
class AppStatsCtrl {
    /** The data to be used to generate the chart. Represents the categories and its data. */
    public categorycount: Array<{
        key: string;
        name: string;
        y: number;
    }> = [];
    /** The hits data for the selected course. */
    public coursehits: null | Array<{
        hdrtitle: string;
        key: string;
        name: string;
        visibilityLevel: number;
        y: number;
    }> = null;
    /** The chart itself. */
    public myChart: null | Highcharts.ChartObject = null;
    /** whether to show the "Reports" button. */
    public showReportsButton: boolean;
    /** The breadcrumbs to show on top of the page. */
    public breadcrumbs: Array<{ name: string; url: string }>;
    /** The message to show to the user if fetching the data fails. */
    private NO_RESPONSE_USER_ERROR_MESSAGE =
        "Sorry, we couldn't get the data for the chart. We don't know what went wrong :(";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** The chart itself. */
public myChart: null | Highcharts.ChartObject = null;
/** whether to show the "Reports" button. */
public showReportsButton: boolean
```

You've mostly done "rearrange the words" documentation. This is where you take the variable name and add a comment where the words are in a different order or are written using synonyms.

If the only thing you can say about a property is just a restating of its name, then you've done a good job naming it, and you should delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan already said, being able to properly name a variable so that other people can immediately understand what you are talking about is the best thing you can do.

All these comments:

```
/** The chart itself. */
public myChart: null | Highcharts.ChartObject = null;
/** whether to show the "Reports" button. */
public showReportsButton: boolean;
/** The breadcrumbs to show on top of the page. */
public breadcrumbs: Array<{ name: string; url: string }>;
/** The message to show to the user if fetching the data fails. */
private NO_RESPONSE_USER_ERROR_MESSAGE =
```

are in my opinion redundant, as they say nothing more than what the name of the variable already says.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to document variables in a block is to list to comment in a block immediately before. This is good practice when using programs such as visual studio's that allow you to minimize comments. But as is stated previously, the most important thing is good names.

```
/*myChart: The chat itself
 *showReports: whether to show the "Reports" button. 
 *breadcrumbs: The breadcrumbs to show on top of the page
 *No response: The message to show to the user if fetching the data fails.
*/
public myChart: null | Highcharts.ChartObject = null;

public showReportsButton: boolean;

public breadcrumbs: Array<{ name: string; url: string }>;

private NO_RESPONSE_USER_ERROR_MESSAGE =
    "Sorry, we couldn't get the data for the chart. We don't know what went wrong :(";
```